# JQuery multiple input fields of each row keyup function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I am trying to make my jquery code in working order but its not working at all, I don't know whats a problem behind it but it contains multiple text boxes in multiple rows,  each row calculates its own sum

Here is [Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/rte00jn4/3/)

Here is my Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.employee input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
        var basic_salary = parseInt($('input[name^=txtMonthlyRate]').val());
        var advance_salary = parseInt($('input[name^=txtAdvance]').val());
        var recover_comm = parseInt($('input[name^=txtRecovery]').val());
        var sales_comm = parseInt($('input[name^=txtSales]').val());
        var deduction_salary = parseInt($('input[name^=txtDeduction]').val());
        var adjustment_salary = parseInt($('input[name^=txtAdjustment]').val());
        var total_sum = ((basic_salary+recover_comm+sales_comm) - (deduction_salary + advance_salary)) + adjustment_salary;
        $('input[name^=txtTotal]').val(total_sum);
        console.log(total_sum)
); 
});
```

Comment: You're running that on .employee keyup, I don't see that class in your markup

Comment: opps sorry i forgot to update that here you go, I updated my fiddle on this link `https://jsfiddle.net/rte00jn4/3/`

Comment: That fiddle is broken needs a  closing `}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The txtSales1, txtDeduction1, txtAdjustment1 variables are camel cased in   your javascript, but not on the html input name. So these return NaN.

**UPDATE** Also, you need to set the context of what you're referring to using the second parameter of a selector function:

```
$('.employee input[type="text"]').keyup(function(e) { 
    var $scope = $(this).closest('.employee');
    var basic_salary = parseInt($('input[name^=txtMonthlyRate]', $scope).val());
    var advance_salary = parseInt($('input[name^=txtAdvance]', $scope).val());
    var recover_comm = parseInt($('input[name^=txtRecovery]', $scope).val());
    var sales_comm = parseInt($('input[name^=txtSales]', $scope).val());
    var deduction_salary = parseInt($('input[name^=txtDeduction]', $scope).val());
    var adjustment_salary = parseInt($('input[name^=txtAdjustment]', $scope).val());
    var total_sum = ((basic_salary+recover_comm+sales_comm) - (deduction_salary + advance_salary)) + adjustment_salary;
    $('input[name^=txtTotal]', $scope).val(total_sum); 
});
```

Comment: Yup. When you run into things like this console.log your variables, if they aren't returning what you expect then look at the inputs and js and make sure they match.

Comment: I tried to make it working and it works but the only problem is instead of calculating the sum in its relative total field it updates all the fields

Comment: Can you please test the this fiddle now https://jsfiddle.net/rte00jn4/4/ I made it working but it only works with the first row and secondly it updates the **total fields** of all rows with same value I only need to fix it but i can't

Comment: it's because you're doing this `('input[name^=txtTotal]').val(total_sum);`

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the fact that you need to scope what you're referring to using the second parameter of the selector function.

Comment: @JasonBoss: Your answer is pretty good! But it is not `scope` is just matching another selector

Comment: In keeping consistent with jQuery documentation, I should have used the term 'context' rather than 'scope', but it's conceptually similar. Since 'this' refers to the element that triggered a keyup event, we're finding the closest element with an employee class and using that to define the context.

Answer (score 0):

The `txttotal1` needs to be changed to `txtTotal1`
The fiddle needs a closing `}`

Comment: can you please preview the updated link and help me to fix in your second last comment